# calculate annual cases after reshaping dataframe in R

Tags: r, reshape, calculated-columns

I am working in `R` and I want to calculate the last column `Annual_Cases` based on the available years for each surgeon. The variable `Years` was reported per each 3-year time interval. Some surgeons were working in more than 1 hospital.

Here is my code that needs edits and my data

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
df %>% drop_na(Cases) %>% group_by(Surgeon)%>% summarise(Annaul_Cases= sum(Cases))/n,  na.rm=T)-> df # I need to calculate n column (number of years the surgeon were in service)


structure(list(Serial.ID = c(215, 522, 903, 1210, 1591, 1898, 
2279, 2586, 2967, 3274, 3655, 3962, 4343, 4650, 5031, 5338, 330, 
1018, 1706, 2394, 3082, 3770, 4458, 5146), Surgeon = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Center = c("Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Maimonides Medical Center", 
"St. Vincents Hospital and Medical Center", "Mount Sinai Hospital", 
"Mount Sinai Hospital", "Mount Sinai Hospital", "Mount Sinai Hospital", 
"Mount Sinai Hospital", "Mount Sinai Hospital", "Mount Sinai Hospital", 
"Mount Sinai Hospital"), Years = c("1996-1998", "1996-1998", 
"1999-2001", "1999-2001", "2002-2004", "2002-2004", "2005-2007", 
"2005-2007", "2008-2010", "2008-2010", "2011-2013", "2011-2013", 
"2014-2016", "2014-2016", "2017-2019", "2017-2019", "1996-1998", 
"1999-2001", "2002-2004", "2005-2007", "2008-2010", "2011-2013", 
"2014-2016", "2017-2019"), Cases = c(377, 19, 223, NA, 27, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 110, 18, 13, 
17, 4, 1), Deaths = c("10", "1", "6", "NA", "0", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Annual_Cases = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my desired output and my used manual formula for that.
[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the various Years for a surgeon don't overlap?

Comment: In your picture, it looks like you want to ignore year ranges with unknown cases? Is this intended? I guess it depends on knowing why those rows are likely unavailable -- are they missing at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First summarize to get sums for each year span, then summarize again to aggregate over all year spans.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  drop_na(Cases) %>% 
  summarize(Cases = sum(Cases), .by = c(Surgeon, Years)) %>%
  summarize(Annual_Cases = sum(Cases) / (n() * 3), .by = Surgeon)
```

Result:

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Surgeon Annual_Cases
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 A              71.8 
2 B               9.06
```

This solution assumes each year span is always 3 years. If not, you’ll need to use an approach like @JonSpring’s using `separate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::n_distinct()` to get the number of unique triennium. Since there's already answers with `summarise`, I´ll use `mutate`, so the output will look more like your spreadsheet.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Cases)) %>% 
  mutate(
    .by = c(Surgeon),
    Annual_Cases = sum(Cases, na.rm = TRUE)/(3 * n_distinct(Years)))

# ---------------   
> df1 %>% 
    select(1:2, last_col()) %>% 
    slice_head(by = Surgeon, n = 3)

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Serial.ID Surgeon Annual_Cases
      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1       215 A              71.8 
2       522 A              71.8 
3       903 A              71.8 
4      1706 B               9.06
5      2394 B               9.06
6      3082 B               9.06
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Years` always spans over 3 years, try:

```r
> X = aggregate(Cases ~ Surgeon + Years, data = df1, sum) 
> tapply(X$Cases, X$Surgeon, \(x) round(sum(x) / (length(x) * 3L)))

 A  B 
72  9
```